# Application restart if i changed the launcher activity in XML manifest

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have a funny problem, I have my project act wired, am following some tutorials and copied some codes, but now I figured that I cannot put any of my activities as launcher activity except the main activity , I looked really deep in it and didn't find anything that make it the only activity that fits to be the launcher activity , is it a manifest problem ? or special flag in the main activity ??!!

please take a look at the main activity and the manifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rozdoum.socialcomponents">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".main.main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".main.postDetails.PostDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/label_post_detail_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.post.createPost.CreatePostActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/label_create_post_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.imageDetail.ImageDetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/label_image_detail_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompat.Black.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.editProfile.createProfile.CreateProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_profile" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.profile.ProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.editProfile.EditProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.post.editPost.EditPostActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_post" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.usersList.UsersListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.followPosts.FollowingPostsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_following_posts"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".main.search.SearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="84e05e27c9fcba7e1de6a47e355a1aa247264a46" />

        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity<MainView, MainPresenter> implements MainView {

    private PostsAdapter postsAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    private TextView newPostsCounterTextView;
    private boolean counterAnimationInProgress = false;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initContentView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        presenter.updateNewPostCounter();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MainPresenter createPresenter() {
        if (presenter == null) {
            return new MainPresenter(this);
        }
        return presenter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case ProfileActivity.CREATE_POST_FROM_PROFILE_REQUEST:
                    refreshPostList();
                    break;
                case CreatePostActivity.CREATE_NEW_POST_REQUEST:
                    presenter.onPostCreated();
                    break;

                case PostDetailsActivity.UPDATE_POST_REQUEST:
                    presenter.onPostUpdated(data);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        attemptToExitIfRoot(floatingActionButton);
    }

    public void refreshPostList() {
        postsAdapter.loadFirstPage();
        if (postsAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removePost() {
        postsAdapter.removeSelectedPost();
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePost() {
        postsAdapter.updateSelectedPost();
    }

    @Override
    public void showCounterView(int count) {
        AnimationUtils.showViewByScaleAndVisibility(newPostsCounterTextView);
        String counterFormat = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.new_posts_counter_format, count, count);
        newPostsCounterTextView.setText(String.format(counterFormat, count));
    }

    private void initContentView() {
        if (recyclerView == null) {
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            swipeContainer = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

            initFloatingActionButton();
            initPostListRecyclerView();
            initPostCounter();
        }
    }

    private void initFloatingActionButton() {
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.addNewPostFab);
        if (floatingActionButton != null) {
            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> presenter.onCreatePostClickAction(floatingActionButton));
        }
    }

    private void initPostListRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(this, swipeContainer);
        postsAdapter.setCallback(new PostsAdapter.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final Post post, final View view) {
                presenter.onPostClicked(post, view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onListLoadingFinished() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthorClick(String authorId, View view) {
                openProfileActivity(authorId, view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCanceled(String message) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                showToast(message);
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
        postsAdapter.loadFirstPage();
    }

    private void initPostCounter() {
        newPostsCounterTextView = findViewById(R.id.newPostsCounterTextView);
        newPostsCounterTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> refreshPostList());

        presenter.initPostCounter();

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                hideCounterView();
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void hideCounterView() {
        if (!counterAnimationInProgress && newPostsCounterTextView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            counterAnimationInProgress = true;
            AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = AnimationUtils.hideViewByAlpha(newPostsCounterTextView);
            alphaAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    counterAnimationInProgress = false;
                    newPostsCounterTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            alphaAnimation.start();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void openPostDetailsActivity(Post post, View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PostDetailsActivity.POST_ID_EXTRA_KEY, post.getId());

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            View imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.postImageView);
            View authorImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.authorImageView);

            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                            new android.util.Pair<>(imageView, getString(R.string.post_image_transition_name)),
                            new android.util.Pair<>(authorImageView, getString(R.string.post_author_image_transition_name))
                    );
            startActivityForResult(intent, PostDetailsActivity.UPDATE_POST_REQUEST, options.toBundle());
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PostDetailsActivity.UPDATE_POST_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    public void showFloatButtonRelatedSnackBar(int messageId) {
        showSnackBar(floatingActionButton, messageId);
    }

    @Override
    public void openCreatePostActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreatePostActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CreatePostActivity.CREATE_NEW_POST_REQUEST);
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void openProfileActivity(String userId, View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.USER_ID_EXTRA_KEY, userId);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && view != null) {

            View authorImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.authorImageView);

            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                            new android.util.Pair<>(authorImageView, getString(R.string.post_author_image_transition_name)));
            startActivityForResult(intent, ProfileActivity.CREATE_POST_FROM_PROFILE_REQUEST, options.toBundle());
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(intent, ProfileActivity.CREATE_POST_FROM_PROFILE_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.profile:
                presenter.onProfileMenuActionClicked();
                return true;

            case R.id.followingPosts:
                Intent followingPosts = new Intent(this, FollowingPostsActivity.class);
                startActivity(followingPosts);
                return true;

            case R.id.search:
                Intent searchIntent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying but from what I gathered, you want other activities to be launched as the main activity? Then just move the intent filter of your main activity to any of the activities that you want to be launched in your manifest. Might also have to modify run configuration in android studio but I am not sure.

Comment: i will explain to you , i want the login activity to be the lunching activiy , but after changing the luncher intent in the manifast to login activity the app will keep looping inside the login activity and will never pass to the upcoming activity , i figured out that even if i created  new activity and marked it as the luncher one it will result in same thing , the app will start the new actvitiy but will never pass to the second one , and the debugger shows no erros at all